# XSLT combine multiple list from one file to table

Tags: xslt, multi-table

I need help with merging several tables of one file into one output.
The files that I get processed perfectly according to the XSLT schema that is listed below. But today I received an interesting file that was not processed as I wanted.

**source file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extdata user="test">
  <scheme name="Order">
    <data>
      <s>
        <d name="CashOrder">
          <f name="ActionDate" type="Date" />
          <f name="AddressId" type="String" />
          <f name="CompanyId" type="String" />
        </d>
      </s>
      <o>
        <d name="CashOrder">
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>10234</f>
            <f>10234</f>
          </r>
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>52817</f>
            <f>52817</f>
          </r>
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>58259</f>
            <f>58259</f>
          </r>
        </d>
      </o>
    </data>
    <data>
      <s>
        <d name="OrderOption">
          <f name="OrderDate" type="Date" />
          <f name="OrderNumber" type="String" />
        </d>
      </s>
      <o>
        <d name="OrderOption">
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>WE30395.c17639</f>
          </r>
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>WE30395.c17639</f>
          </r>
          <r>
            <f>2022-01-24T00:00:00</f>
            <f>WE30395.c17639</f>
          </r>
        </d>
      </o>
    </data>
  </scheme>
</extdata>
```

my XSLT (here they helped me with writing.there was a problem with the recursive processing of the hierarchy)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/extdata/scheme">
      <ValueTable xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <xsl:for-each select="data/s/d/f | data/s/d/d/f">
            <column>
               <Name xsi:type="xs:string">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
               </Name>
               <ValueType>
                  <xsl:if test="@type= 'String'">
                     <Type>xs:string</Type>
                     <StringQualifiers>
                        <Length>150</Length>
                        <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                     </StringQualifiers>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="@type= 'Date'">
                     <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                     <DateQualifiers>
                        <DateFractions>DateTime</DateFractions>
                     </DateQualifiers>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="@type= 'Decimal' or @type= 'Currency'">
                     <Type>xs:decimal</Type>
                     <NumberQualifiers>
                        <Digits>20</Digits>
                        <FractionDigits>4</FractionDigits>
                        <AllowedSign>Any</AllowedSign>
                     </NumberQualifiers>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="@type= 'Integer'">
                     <Type>xs:decimal</Type>
                     <NumberQualifiers>
                        <Digits>20</Digits>
                        <FractionDigits>0</FractionDigits>
                        <AllowedSign>Any</AllowedSign>
                     </NumberQualifiers>
                  </xsl:if>
               </ValueType>
            </column>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="data/o/d/r">
            <row>
               <xsl:for-each select=".//f">
                  <Value>
                     <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </Value>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ValueTable>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output now

```
      <ValueTable xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">ActionDate</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
         <DateQualifiers>
            <DateFractions>DateTime</DateFractions>
         </DateQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">AddressId</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">CompanyId</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">OrderDate</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
         <DateQualifiers>
            <DateFractions>DateTime</DateFractions>
         </DateQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">OrderNumber</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>10234</Value>
      <Value>10234</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>52817</Value>
      <Value>52817</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>58259</Value>
      <Value>58259</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
</ValueTable>
```

need

```
<ValueTable xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">ActionDate</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
         <DateQualifiers>
            <DateFractions>DateTime</DateFractions>
         </DateQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">AddressId</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">CompanyId</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">OrderDate</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
         <DateQualifiers>
            <DateFractions>DateTime</DateFractions>
         </DateQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <column>
      <Name xsi:type="xs:string">OrderNumber</Name>
      <ValueType>
         <Type>xs:string</Type>
         <StringQualifiers>
            <Length>150</Length>
            <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
         </StringQualifiers>
      </ValueType>
   </column>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>10234</Value>
      <Value>10234</Value>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>52817</Value>
      <Value>52817</Value>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>58259</Value>
      <Value>58259</Value>
     <Value>2022-01-24T00:00:00</Value>
      <Value>WE30395.c17639</Value>
   </row>
 </ValueTable>
```

---

Briefly, the structure can be described as follows
I mean this is how I got it

```
<table>
  <header>  
    <column1>
    <column2>
    <column3>
    <column4>
    <column5>
  <header>
<row>
   value1
   value2
   value3
</row>
<row>
   value4
   value5
</row>
</table>
```

but it should be like this

```
<table>
  <header> 
   <column1>
   <column2>
   <column3>
   <column4>
   <column5>
  </header>
<row>
   value1
   value2
   value3
   value4
   value5
</row>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is rather confusing because many values are identical and it's hard to see what goes where. It's also not clear if there can be more `data` elements and if so, what should the result be then.

AFAICT, this produces the expected result for the given example. For clarity, I have omitted the header part, which seems to be working fine.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   
<xsl:template match="/extdata/scheme">
    <ValueTable xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <!-- header -->

        <!-- data -->
        <xsl:for-each select="data[1]/o/d/r">
            <row>
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//data/o/d/r[$i]/f">
                    <Value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </Value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </ValueTable>
</xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```